# firebase - kotlin - Hashmap type inference failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to use firebase and Hashmap and I've tried GenericTypeIndicator but I've found the following error: `type inference failed`

The code:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("aaa").child(game_id).child("bbbb")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            val type = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,String>>() {}

            val precios : HashMap<String,String>  = dataSnapshot.getValue(type!!)
            liveData.postValue(precios)

        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `HashMap` is optional, so give this a try:

```
val type = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,String>?>() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with your snapcode and what I change in it so I passed this error is this

```
   val precios : HashMap<String,String>  = dataSnapshot.getValue(type)!!
```

instead of

```
    val precios : HashMap<String,String>  = dataSnapshot.getValue(type!!)
```

Hope that helps others as it helped me cause the other solution didn't work for me

Happy coding :)